# Perspective control in MATLAB 3D figures

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, computational-geometry, projection, angle

How to change the vanishing points (P1,P2,P3) in the perspective in MATLAB 3D figures?
Below there is a scheme of explanation what I mean:

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You might want to provide some code that creates a figure like this in MATLAB. Perhaps you could find some clues in [`view`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/view.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to control the perspective appearance in a plot, you'll want to first change the [`Projection` property of the axes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#budumk7-Projection) to `perspective`. Then you can change the various [camera properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/defining-scenes-with-camera-graphics.html) of the axes to get the view you want. The important ones for adjusting how the perspective looks are the `CameraViewAngle` and `CameraPosition`.

I have found that a "realistic" perspective view can be achieved using a `CameraViewAngle` of about 30 degrees, mimicking the preferred viewing area of the human eye:

[image]

The default `CameraViewAngle` is about 6.6, so setting it to 30 will cause the view to appear zoomed-out. You will then want to change the `CameraPosition` so that it is closer to the `CameraTarget`, thus zooming the view back in. You can use a larger `CameraViewAngle` if you want a more exaggerated perspective (like a [fisheye lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisheye_lens)).

Comment: Thank you very much. It is not directly related with vanishing points. But it is what I need.